# DOS batch, determine if last monday of the month?

Tags: batch-file, dos

Is it possible within a DOS batch file to test if the current day is the last Monday of the month? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work...test for the day of the week, and then whether the date is greater than 24 (or 23 for months with 30 days, or 21 in the case of February...that'd be 22 in leap years, so you'd want to add that test as well):

```
@echo off
set Day=%date:~0,3%
IF "%Day%"=="Mon" set Monday=1
set today=%date:~7,2%
set lim=24
if "%date:~4,2%"=="02" set lim=21
if "%date:~4,2%"=="04" set lim=23
if "%date:~4,2%"=="06" set lim=23
if "%date:~4,2%"=="09" set lim=23
if "%date:~4,2%"=="11" set lim=23
if "%today%" GTR "%lim%" set Last=1
if "%Monday%"==1 goto itsMonday
:itsMonday
if "%Last%"=="1" echo last monday of the month
:end
```